# Windows Named pipes not working over network?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, ipc, named-pipes

I'm encountering a strange problems with Named pipes on Windows in C#.

Client:

```
    NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("default-PC","mypipe");

    pipeStream.Connect();
    BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(pipeStream);
    sw.Write((byte[]) data);
```

Server:

```
    NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe");
    byte[] dataAll = null;
    pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
    dataAll = new BinaryReader(pipeStream).ReadBytes(1024 * 1000 * 512);
```

--

If I use "." as a server name in the constructor for the NamedPipeClientStream everything works correctly, i.e. the server fills the dataAll object.

Now the strange thing is that **if I on the other hand put the network name of the computer("default-PC") in the NamedPipeClientStream** like shown in the code above **then no data is read on the server** as ReadBytes in the server code returns an empty array.

This could understandable I was running the server and client on two different computers but they are both running on the same machine.  The only difference being whether the "server name" parameter in NamedPipeClientStream **is** "." or the actual network name (or even localhost).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the conclusion is this:

If the Server name parameter in NamedPipeClientStream is something else than "." then the underlying implementation is through a transport layer that supports a maximum of 64k in a single Write operation.  The problem is that if you Write more than 64k then the data just disappears instead of throwing an exception.

The solution is to use the NamedPipeClientStream directly and Write the data in less than 64kb chunks.

Comment: @user357320: In general, this is not true. On my 64-bit Vista machine your code works with both "." and <machine-name> for data sizes up to at least 50MB. With data size 500MB, my service process crashes with OutOfMemoryException, with both "." and <machine-name>.

Comment: I ran the code on a Win7 x64 machine.  Perhaps the implementation is different but in any case the data never arrived when I attempted to send over 64k - at least with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that both "." and "localhost" are considered special names and don't use the normal network connections, but a loopback of some sort.

When you specify a computer name, even your own computer's name, it uses the standard network protocols/stack/etc.

You probably need to open a firewall port. TCP 445. Also, *by default*, Windows allows all outgoing communications. You should only need to add an inbound port exception. Your configuration may vary of course.
[.NET 3.5 (C#) Named pipes over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202935/net-3-5-c-named-pipes-over-network)

Comment: I turned off the firewall and there was no change.  Anyway the pipe connects correctly it is just that no data seems go through it.  Also neither "localhost" or the network name work, only "." (or not specifying a server).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't catch that. I am at a loss then. I just tried pasting your code into two projects and I used both localhost and my actual workstation name. Both worked. In my client I defined data as "    byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };"

Comment: Also, I am using VS 2010, .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, on a 64-bit Windows box.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your help.  I'm scratching my head over this one.

Comment: It is connected to the length of the message. Above around 50k and the data disappears.  I'll have to take a better look at a maximum data length option that must be set somewhere.

Comment: But the longer data block came through with "."? I just looked at the MS docs for non-managed CreateNamedPipe <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150(VS.85).aspx > and in the remarks it says "The actual buffer size reserved for each end of the named pipe is either the system default, the system minimum or maximum, or the specified size rounded up to the next allocation boundary." But, they don't say what the MAX REALLY IS. Mind you, the .NET version may be completely rewritten and not use this API either...

Comment: It seems like the maximum size is 64k (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/a3ee3c46-9afc-4a6a-b9d2-26b8230942d9/) When using "." as the server then the pipes are probably implemented in shared memory where the message limit is much higher.  Solution seems to be to chop the message into 64k chunks.  It is though strange that no exception came up, the data just disappeared.