# C# named pipes over a network

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an app that requires communication over a network. I was following the MSDN doc for named pipes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

I've tried the code from MSDN but no luck.

I saw that "." has to be replaced with the network name on the client side, which I did. I tried the network name and the server PC name but both failed to connect to the server (my laptop).

Now I'm not sure what to do - any advice? (The code below gets me "The network path was not found")

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

class PipeClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
            new NamedPipeClientStream("xxx.xxx.x.x", "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {

            // Connect to the pipe or wait until the pipe is available.
            Console.Write("Attempting to connect to pipe...");
            pipeClient.Connect();

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to pipe.");
            Console.WriteLine("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open.",
               pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
            {
                // Display the read text to the console
                string temp;
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: the server must be able to accept pipe requests!

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - the code is the same as the MSDN doc link above, except I change the "." as I mentioned. How do you enable named pipes or how would you know if the server is accepting requests?

Comment: I hope that the link that I provided you works out ..sorry too me a minute to respond I got side tracked answering another question.. let us know how this works out for you if you still have issues.. happy coding..

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a computer name, even your own computer's name, it uses the standard network protocols/stack/etc.

You probably need to open a firewall port. TCP 445. Also, *by default*, Windows allows all outgoing communications. You should only need to add an inbound port exception. Your configuration may vary of course.
[.NET 3.5 (C#) Named pipes over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202935/net-3-5-c-named-pipes-over-network)

Comment: I enabled TCP 445 for the server. I figured a problem with the client code on the MSDN doc, it would always close the console because it needs arguments, so I'm using this code instead: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support - Using either the network name or server pc name, I get "The network path was not found" when it does pipeClient.Connect()

Comment: Apparently it's limited to LANs... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244367/c-sharp-3-5-connecting-named-pipe-across-network - Is there 1 that works over the network via a router?

Comment: Are you wanting NamedPipeClientStream or NamedPipeServerStream

Comment: Look at this MSDN: site as well it has some good info as well as code also can you show the code that you are using so that I can test it on my end with my namedpipes .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx

Comment: I need both? NamedPipeClientStream is the problem as I cannot connect. Above link, proves you can use named pipes over the network.

Comment: would need to see how you have implemented your code .. it's hard to say without seeing.. and if you are worried about the ip address just replace it with xxx.xx.xxx it's the logic that we are most interested in seeing here.

Comment: I have the same issue wonder if there is something on my side that's preventing ..I am working at Dept of Defense.. so firewall and other DMZ Crap is a major pain..

Comment: I figured that you need (on Windows) to have the Server service started (I had it disabled on both machines) but still didn't solve it. I'm trying to make a notification system, but since I'm new to this, I'm trying the basics first.

Comment: What type of notification system.. have you considered looking at Windows Service..

Comment: A system where if say a button was pressed/triggered on the server end, the clients would get a notification via a desktop app. Something simple like that. What is the "Windows Service" you mention? Link?